# Is it possible to use GNOME Maps in Ubuntu with Unity?

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome

OMGUbuntu featured a [Gnome Maps](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/09/10-best-features-gnome-3-10) application which I would very much like to use in Ubuntu as well.

[image]

Is this possible to use Gnome Maps at all on a default installation of Ubuntu 12.04 - or should I expect Unity related issues?

(Of course I could just go ahead, download and install Gnome Maps. But fact is that *I can't find a way of getting hold of the software really* - I'm new to this. Therefore I'm asking this question hypothetically.)

Comment: Here is the gnome-maps sourcecode http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gnome-maps/3.10/gnome-maps-3.10.0.tar.xz

Comment: @blade19899 This is nice, but it doesn't come with build instructions.

Comment: most common build commands are: `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install`.

Comment: @blade19899 Ok, I've done this now. I still had to install `ìntltool` and `glib-compile-schemas`. The latter is not available in synaptics, therefore I had to get it via `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev`. After that I could successfully gnome maps. However, running the executable `gnome-maps` gives the error: `./gnome-maps: 18: exec: -I: not found`.

Comment: If gnome-maps doesn't work you can always use [emerillion](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2009/11/desktop-map-viewer-emerillion-for-ubuntu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user @blade19899 for the help with this answer.

The source for **Gnome Maps 3.10** is available at:
http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gnome-maps/3.10/

1. Download and extract the file.
2. Install missing packages to build gnome-maps:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev intltool
   ```
3. Build:

   ```
   ./configure && make && sudo make install
   ```
4. The executable is located in:

   ```
   .../gnome-maps-3.10.0/src/gnome-maps
   ```

Unfortunately, running gnome-maps returns an error `./gnome-maps: 18: exec: -I: not found`. It's not working, but it isn't officially supported on 12.04 either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will run on Ubuntu under Unity just fine. However, you will run into some issues if you are trying to run it on 12.04, as it is a new GNOME application, and thus requires much newer GNOME libraries than are included in 12.04.

You'll need to use the Ubuntu-GNOME PPA that includes 3.10, which may only be available for Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Ah, that's said. I'll have to wait for the next LTS release then. The gnome maps application has a search suggest feature and 'find my location' which are both very neat. I've found a "maps for gnome and ubuntu" application in the software center which does not have either of those two features.